# APIConnect on Bluemix Developer Portal custom URL

Tags: dns, ibm-cloud, apiconnect

I am trying to configure the developer portal for a catalog I created to be pointed to using a custom URL. I have set my DNS entries at the DNS provider correctly, and mapped the CNAME entry for my  subdomain to the portal URL provided in APIManager. It resolves correctly and pings using my domain name.

So when I ping: api.mydomain.com, it gets resolved to the provided IBM Portal URL: space-organization.apiconnect.ibmcloud.com.

The problem is that when I try to open the Portal using my URL on the browser http://api.mydoamin.com, request times out. Which means it resolves, but the server doesn't respond.

I believe this is a problem in HTTP server configuration on the portal to accept requests with host as api.mydomain.com.

How can I configure that? Appreciate your quick response since this is an important project, first of a kind.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, setting up a custom domain on the portal or API gateway hosts requires intervention by the cloud operations team. Open a support ticket if you need this enabled.

Answer (score 0):

An important bit of information needed here when considering APIc and custom domains for APIc resources when using APIc in Bluemix:

> When using IBM Bluemix to create the APIc service instances, support
>   for custom domains for APIc resources is restricted to the more
>   powerful plans.   From what I understand now, this means the APIc
>   Professional plan and above is required to request custom domain support.

For details on the APIc plans that are available - see: https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/api-connect?env_id=ibm:yp:us-south&taxonomyNavigation=services

Note:  You can use the BX CLI (Bluemix CLI) to upgrade a service instance to a new plan:

```
bx service update SERVICE_INSTANCE [-p NEW_PLAN] [-c PARAMETERS_AS_JSON] [-t TAGS]
```

This plan upgrade would be required if you wanted to use custom domains with APIc and were not using an APIc service instance that was at or above the **Professional** service plan level.   Once you have the right plan, as Matt said, to use custom domains with APIc you'll need to open a support ticket to request custom domain implementation and provide the required content required for that implementation.